# XSLT Template not using parameter

Tags: javascript, xml, xslt

I cannot get the xslt parameter `zoneid` to be used:

```
    <xsl:template name="ad">
    <xsl:param name="zoneid" />
    <script><![CDATA[
    var m3_u = (location.protocol=='https:'?'https://XX.php':'http://XX.php');
    var m3_r = Math.floor(Math.random()*99999999999);
    if (!document.MAX_used) document.MAX_used = ',';
    document.write ("<scr"+"ipt type='text/javascript' src='"+m3_u);
    document.write ("?zoneid={$zoneid}"/>&amp;target=_blank");]]></script>
    </xsl:template>
```

Now I run the template by this:

```
 <xsl:template name="ad_300x600">
 <xsl:param name="state" />
 <xsl:param name="locid" />
 <xsl:when test="$state='FL'"><xsl:call-template name="ad"><xsl:with-param name="zoneid">341</xsl:with-param></xsl:call-template></xsl:when>
 </template>
```

And here is the resulting HTML:

```
        <script>
        var m3_u = (location.protocol=='https:'?'https://XX.php':'http://XX.php');
        var m3_r = Math.floor(Math.random()*99999999999);
        if (!document.MAX_used) document.MAX_used = ',';
        document.write ("<scr"+"ipt type='text/javascript' src='"+m3_u);
        document.write ("?zoneid={$zoneid}"/>&amp;target=_blank");
        </script>
```

**As you can see in the resulting HTML Its saying `{$zoneid}`.**

I've also tried `<xsl:value-of select="$zoneid"/>` with no luck either.

Not sure what to do here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to use the syntax of [attribute value templates](https://www.w3.org/TR/2000/WD-xslt11-20001212/#attribute-value-templates) within literal text content.

This simply does not work - the XSLT engine doesn't look for AVTs in text content.

To output the variable you need to end the CData section, add a `<xsl:value-of select="$zoneid"/>` (and start a new CData section afterwards).